# Expire only one selected variable inside $_SESSION (instead of the whole $_SESSION)

Tags: php, session-timeout

I'm writing a program where I need to expire a selected variable in the `$_SESSION` array.

Now I know how to expire the whole `$_SESSION` variable but my need is *selective*, i.e. to only expire `$_SESSION['trial_period_1']`,  `$_SESSION['trial_period_credits']` variables after 1 day.

I want the user to stay logged in, just want the trial period variable to end (the session timeout is 1 month).

I was thinking of doing it this way, but decided to ask since I'm sure someone knows a more elegant solution to this.

`$_SESSION['trial_period_credits'] = 4;
$_SESSION['trial_period_credits_expire'] = time() + 86400;`

Then check it every time for each variable

`if ( $_SESSION['trial_period_credits_expire'] < time() ) { ...`

**Is there a better way to do this?** My solution seems kind of messy as it requires creating a lot of unnecessary session variables.

Comment: unset($_SESSION['trial_period_1']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unset`. Try with -

```
if ( $_SESSION['trial_period_credits_expire'] < time() ) {
    unset($_SESSION['trial_period_1']);
    unset($_SESSION['trial_period_credits']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

identify the key and use `unset`:

```
if ( $_SESSION['trial_period_credits_expire'] < time() ) {
    unset($_SESSION['trial_period_1']);// will unset the $_SESSION for key trial_period_1 only.rest of the $_SESSION will remain.
}
```